# Jquery toggle input value and button class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a PHP page that loads a form with pre-populated values from a MySQL database. Users are able to edit the form and update it with their desired data, this works.

I would like to offer them the ability to toggle **one** of the fields if it's *not applicable*. By doing so, the field will be populated with the text 'N/A' and the button class should change to 'btn-warning'. When clicked again the 'N/A' should be removed and the previous data re-inserted - is this possible?

So far I have it sort of working... when the button is clicked the input is populated with 'N/A' and the class changes, however it doesn't toggle, i.e the previous data doesn't re-appear and the 'N/A' remains.

I have created a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6pqugkg3/2/), any help is appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ipclear").click(function() {
    $("#ip").val('N/A');
    $(this).toggleClass('btn-default').toggleClass('btn-warning');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" name='ip' id="ip" class='form-control' value="1.2.3.4">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="ipclear">Not Applicable</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the text in a variable before toggle and set it again during next click.

**Here is a working example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var toggleText = $("#ip").val();
  $("#ipclear").click(function() {
    if ($("#ip").val() != 'N/A') {
      toggleText = $("#ip").val();
      $("#ip").val('N/A');
    } else
      $("#ip").val(toggleText);
    $(this).toggleClass('btn-default').toggleClass('btn-warning');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" name='ip' id="ip" class='form-control' value="1.2.3.4">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="ipclear">Not Applicable</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is perfect! Thanks for the explanation and working example :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not restoring the value of the input field in your code.  Somewhere you need to remember the old value and restore it on second click.

I updated your JSFIDDLE with a possible solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/Doogie/6pqugkg3/5/

Some more tips:

If you have more than one field, then you need to remember the original value of each of them. One way you could do that is via data- attributes on the input elemnts:

`<input value="currentValue"  data-orig="originalValueFromDB" id="ip" ....>`

You can get the original value with JQuery just as any other attribute:

`var origValue = $('#ip').attr('data-orig');  // origValue = "originalValueFromDB'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign your text value in a variable and reassign after toggle.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.ipVal = $("#ip").val();
  $("#ipclear").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('btn-default btn-warning');
    if($(this).hasClass('btn-default')){ //OR $(this).hasClass('btn-default')
     $("#ip").val(window.ipVal);
    }else{
     $("#ip").val('N/A');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" name='ip' id="ip" class='form-control' value="1.2.3.4">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="ipclear">Not Applicable</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @johnny_s : After changing text in textbox and then toggle which value you need to populate previous value or initial value ?